# How to search matching charecter in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails WHERE Sample_name LIKE '$userinput' OR Client_name LIKE '$userinput1%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I am trying to execute above query, but its outputting full details from mysql database.

how to fix this issue?
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Missing `%` -

```
Sample_name LIKE '%$userinput%' OR Client_name LIKE '%$userinput1%'
```

[Check the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: if i have more than one query like i updated than how to achive the goal sir?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: no sir its again executing * only i mean its its giving whole data as output

Comment: if i didnt give any input also , than also its showing all the data

Comment: all the data means which is not matching also

Comment: It will check the both columns. If any of them matches it will return else not. If you want to match both then use `AND`.

Comment: than how it is working if i didnt give any input also ??

Comment: That has to be taken care of. You cant allow blanks.

Comment: how to take care of such cases??

Comment: That magic word is **(validation)** that might be done at both ends

Answer (score 0):

You have to use '%' operator. A `Like` always expect a `%`. Try this -

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails WHERE Sample_name LIKE '%$userinput'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: It's not *always*, it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

you missed `%` sign in `$userinput`

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails WHERE Sample_name LIKE '%$userinput%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```